# sfMelodyPlugin with Propel in symfony1.4

Tags: facebook, twitter, symfony-1.4, propel

I've been dealing with this plugin in order to connect my symfony 1.4 application to Twitter, Facebook and Google and still cant make it work, anyone has been able to make it work? Have you followed any tutorial? I'd really appreciate some help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I am a refugee from sfFacebookConnect. The documentation is okay, but doesn't cover everything that you need to know.

Also, if you look on GitHub there are at least two sample applications that use sfMelody. They are good starting points. Also, the author is very involved on his Github repository and regularly answers questions.

What is your specific problem and perhaps I can help?

Comment: I think its a combination of problems, first of all my system is using PropelORM and not doctrine as in the examples; the sfMelody example you say is usefull but laks a lot of examplanation and code (like the php-openid lib and configuration), the Token table doesn't have some user specific methods used, and there is more. But i think  i should give it a second try, for now i'm using BrowserId authentication witch is great btw